# Find identity element for commutative group with composition $a*b = (a+b)(1+ab)^{-1}.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all real numbers $a,b,...$ whose absolute values are less than $1.$ Define a law of composition $\star$ by the formula $a\star b = (a+b)(1+ab)^{-1}$ where $a + b$ and $ab$ denote the customary sum and product of the real numbers $a$ and $b.$
a. Prove that $G,$ with $\star$ for the law of composition, is a commutative group. 
b. What is the identity element of $G$ and the inverse of $0?$

a. $b\star a = (b+a)(1+ab)^{-1}= a\star 
b$

b. Let, the identity element be denoted by $e,$ and for any element $a\in G,$ get: $ae= a.$
$a\star e = (a+e)(1+a)^{-1}= a,$

Apply two ways:

1: Taking $1= e,$ get:
$a\star e = (a+e)(e+a)^{-1}\implies  a\star e= e,$ 
But, $a^2= e,$ is specific to a given element $a$ in the group.

For, another element $b,$ it would be $b^2= e.$

So, each element is inverse of itself.

2: Taking $1\ne e,$ get:
$a\star e = a=  (a+e)(1+a)^{-1},$
$\implies a(1+a)= (a+e),$
$\implies a+ a^2= a+e,$
$\implies a^2= e.$
So, get the same result.

Have an additional question: do we need to compute $a^2$ too, as $a^2= a\star a?$ Though, that would make it an infinite recursive computation of $a^2,$ as shown below:
$a^2 = a\star a=(a+a)(1+a^2).$

Also, what is the significance of the condition that the set of all real numbers $a,b,...$ whose absolute values are less than $1.$

***Edit :*** The root lies in $\star$ being different from the customary multiplication given by $ab.$
Hence $a^2= a\cdot a,$ and that means apart from the group operation, two more operations are in use: customary addition and multiplication; which is new for me. I considered till now, only the groups where only the group operation was used. Though see that in Dihedral groups too, apart from the group operation of composition, there were operations of rotation and reflection.

Comment: Note that $a*0=\frac{a+0}{1+0a}=a$, so $0$ acts as a neutral. Not sure why you want to say $ae=a$ - this is *not* an ordinary multiplication.

Comment: @StinkingBishop You seem to take $0=e,$ but that means addition operation is implied. Also, I took $ae=a,$ by the definition of identity.

Comment: No, the definition of identity is $a*e=a$ for *whatever operation $*$ you are dealing with*. Here you are dealing with $*$ so we want $a*e=a$. It is not a problem if the same element *happens to be* the identity for two different operations, .e.g. here $0$ is the identity for both $*$ and $+$.

Comment: The significance of the interval $(-1, 1)$ ... it is all in the eye of the beholder, but I would say the bottom line is that $a*b=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}(a)+\tanh^{-1}(b))$ and $\tanh:\mathbb R\to (-1,1)$, i.e. $\tanh$ is an *isomorphism* of $(\mathbb R, +)$ to $((-1, 1), *)$.

Comment: Oops, my answer is essentially identical to the above comments by Stinking Bishop. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For b, note that you have to solve the equation

$$ a \star e = a \qquad\text{for any } a \in G. $$

Plugging the definition of $\star$, this amounts to finding $e$ so that

$$ \frac{a+e}{1+ae} = a \qquad\text{for any } a \in G. $$

Multiplying both sides by $1+ae$ and rearranging gives the equation

$$(1 - a^2)e = 0 \qquad\text{for any } a \in G. $$

Since $a^2 \neq 1$ for any $a \in G$, this equation can hold true only when $e = 0$. Therefore we conclude that $e = 0$ is the identity for the operation $\star$.

Now, the relation $e \star e = e$ shows that $e$ is the inverse of $e$ itself. (This is true for any group $G$.)

---

The significance of taking $G = (-1, 1)$ arises from the observation that there exists a group homomorphism $\phi$ from $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ to $(G, \star)$ given by

$$ \phi : \mathbb{R} \to G, \qquad \phi(x) = \tanh x. $$

Clearly $\phi$ is a bijective function. Moreover, the addition formula for $\tanh$ shows that $\phi$ is indeed a homomorphism:

$$ \phi(x+y) = \tanh(x+y) = \frac{\tanh x + \tanh y}{1 + \tanh x \tanh y} = \phi(x) \star \phi(y). $$

Comment: Note that even *before* solving a), this *bijection* $\phi$ (at this stage we cannot yet speak of an isomorphism) directly proves, by [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure), that $(G,\star)$ is an abelian group with identity element $\phi(0)=0.$

Comment: The application of 
$ \phi(x+y) = \tanh(x+y)$ shows it being implied in the problem. Can there be other applications of this group operation?